# Vertical jump and body weight

Tags: muscle-mass, vertical-jump

So I got 2 months and I want to maintain my vertical jump or increase a bit. But also I want to get my bodyweight from 52kg to 57-59kg in those two months.
I would like to know how I would be able to do this. 
Ps. I want to mainly increase upper body size.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing 5-7kg in 2 months is something you can do while staying pretty lean.  To increase primarily upper body mass and still maintain your vertical jump is also pretty easy.

**Diet**

Your diet needs to change so that you are increasing your mass by no more than .75 kg a week.  That will keep you pretty lean, so it won't adversely affect the vertical too much (fat resists changing velocity more than rigid muscle).  That pace will put you right at 6 kg over 8 weeks.

I do recommend the following practice on training days:

- 500 ml of skim milk with 5g creatine pre-workout
- 500 ml of skim milk with 5g creatine to sip on throughout the workout
- 500 ml of skim milk with 1 scoop protein powder post-workout

During non-training days you can either skip this altogether, or just have one 2-scoop protein shake during that time of day.

All other food should be regular food.  The reason for this is to time carbohydrates and protein to give you more energy throughout your workouts, as well as put your body in the best condition to make use of the protein and carbs.  I.e. more goes to muscle and less to fat.  (Source is the [Performance Nutrition Encyclopedia](http://www.store.jtsstrength.com/resources/performance-nutrition-encyclopedia)).

**Training Changes**

You need to maintain your lower body strength while building your upper body strength/mass.

For a training split, I would use 3 days where two days are upper body days and 1 is a lower body day.  Feel free to adapt things to suit you better, but this basic structure will help:

**Day 1: Triceps/Shoulders/Lats**

- Primary Press movement (overhead, bench, dumbbells or barbells) 3x10-15
- Shoulder triple sets (one set would be lateral raise, front raise, and rear delt raise) 3x10-15
- Triceps pushdowns: 4x10-15 (2 sets with a hammer grip, 2 sets with a straight grip)
- Pull-ups / Lat Pull Downs 3x5-10
- Ab work, 50 reps your choice.

**Day 2: Lower body maintenance/traps**

- Squats: work up to 3-8 RM  (cycle 8RM, 5RM, 3RM)
- Box Jumps: 75% 7x3 (more to keep in practice with the movement)
- Snatch Grip High Pulls: 3x5-10
- Glute bridges: 3x10-15 (hold 1-3s at top)
- Standing calf raises 3x10-15

**Day 3: Arms/Biceps/Chest**

- Secondary Press movement (overhead, push press, bench, dumbbells or barbells) 3x10-15
- Chest flies 3x10-15
- Kneeling 1 arm DB rows (AKA Kroc rows) 3x10-15
- DB Curls (your choice of variation) 3x10-15
- Barbell curls: just the empty bar, as many as possible, aim for 50 or more
- Ab work, 50 reps your choice.

**NOTES**

When I write a rep range like 3x10-15, you will be starting with a weight you can hit for 3 sets of 10 and working up to 3 sets of 15.  The goal progression would be 3x10, 3x12, 3x15.  When you hit the max number of reps you increase weight and start over with 3x10.

The only difference for this is with squats, where I have you working up to an 8 rep max, then a 5 rep max, and finally a 3 rep max.  The goal here is to aim for a slightly higher weights each time you cycle through.

This approach will help you increase upper body mass if you eat to support your work, and you really are pushing yourself with the weights.  It's hard to judge what you can do for 3x10 if you've never done work in that range.  If you know your 1 rep max for that exercise, then start with 70% of that.

This is a more bodybuilding approach to training, since the goal here is to add upper body mass and maintain that vertical jump.  The squat work should be enough to maintain or increase your strength, and the box jumps keep the practice up.  After 3 weeks, you may increase the height of the box and maintain the reps--as long as you are confident you'll be able to hit it.

There's two pressing movements, primarily because triceps account for the majority of your arm mass.  You'll notice I don't have much for forearms.  If you use fat grips with the dumbbell rows, curls, and the secondary press movement you'll do everything needed for them.  The primary press movement should be something where you can overload your triceps more.  Strict pressing, close grip bench pressing, or dumbbell bench with your palms facing each other will all do that.  The secondary press movement can be a push press or other quick movement.  The goal here is to provide 2 days of arm training, but hit them a bit differently than you do on the primary press.

**Parting Thoughts**

What I outlined is just a framework to get you started.  There are a number of bodybuilding templates out there, and the only modifications you need are to keep volume on the legs a little lower and the rep ranges shorter.  Your goal is maintaining strength and power output.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your upper body weight is clean(no fat) you don't have to worry to much ! unless you gain some 10kg only on your upper body. :)
 As for training in 2 months you wont be able to gain 5-6 kg of clean muscle and maintain your vertical leap.
 The best type of training you can do is HIT type (maybe 8 times a week- depending on your level); short and explosive training where you do not engage aerobic type of exercises ! max time of execution would be 10 seconds. 
 Avoid static stretching go for foam roller and dynamic stretching ! 
Eat clean and up your protein intake ! 
**Note : Train as hard as you perform and train in the same manner.**